# set customer entity attribute

Tags: magento2

```
$customer = $this->customerInterfaceFactory
                    ->create()
                    ->setWebsiteId((int) $websiteId)
                    ->setEmail($email)
                    ->setFirstname($firstname)
                    ->setLastname($lastname)
                    ->setCustaccountid($custaccountid);
```

doesn't actually work, the customer attribute is done via installdata.php as below

```
namespace Generic\Customer\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface

{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $eavConfig;
    private $attributeResource;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource
    ) {

        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;

        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;

        $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, "custaccountid");
        $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);



        $eavSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custaccountid', [

            // Attribute parameters

            'type' => 'varchar',

            'label' => 'Customer Account ID',

            'input' => 'text',

            'required' => false,

            'visible' => true,

            'user_defined' => true,

            'sort_order' => 990,

            'position' => 990,

            'system' => 0,

        ]);

        

        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custaccountid');

        $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);

        $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);

        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);
        $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
    }
}
```

Thanks ahead of time!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use setCustomAttribute. Custom attributes for customers don't have its getter/setter function defined, so you should use this intermediary function. You should also use then: getCustomAttributes if you want to retrieve the saved values.

More info: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html

```php
$customer = $this->customerInterfaceFactory
                    ->create()
                    ->setWebsiteId((int) $websiteId)
                    ->setEmail($email)
                    ->setFirstname($firstname)
                    ->setLastname($lastname);

$customer->setCustomAttribute('custaccountid', $custaccountid);
//will allow input of custom attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first load the customer using model like this one :

```
\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer
```

Then try to save the value like this one :

```
$customer->setCustaccountid($custaccountid);
$customer->save():
```

Comment: use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer; causes setup:upgrade to not work. I am using as follows:
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory;
already and that's not working for $customer->setCustaccountid($custaccoundid); and ->save();

Comment: share the whole code where you write above things.

Comment: Regardless, turns out I needed to use setCustomAttribute to influence it. Thanks for your help

Comment: If answer help you, please upvote and accepted as solution, so it will help other in community.

Comment: I didn't use your example since it didn't work and upvoted and accepted the answer above this.